# How to replace Action\Action in a controller with both Get and Post requests

Tags: magento2, action

I'm trying to create a controller, but I need both Get and Post requests in this Controller. What's my alternative?

I can do 2 lines like this

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface;
```

but then what do I use for the Class extends? I used to do Class  extends Action, but that's not an option anymore.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class MyController implements HttpPostActionInterface, HttpGetActionInterface
```